# Offset problem in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, views

I want to use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module to display the top item from a listing.

I've utilized the "Use Pager" to display that one item. But sometimes I want to display the second item, or third item, or X item. I've found the offset option to skip the first item, but the result I get doesn't seem to match. What I get instead is some random item, and not, say, the second item.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally enable random ordering as well? In a randomly ordered list, the second item will always be random as well.

If this is not the case, please provide more information about the configuration of your view. Two ways of doing this are to make a screen shot of the edit form, and to upload the exported view to http://pastebin.com.

Comment: Thanks. But no, I did not utilize the randomly orderly list. Rather, my sort criteria is Content: Post date with a granularity set to "Second". The other configuration of my view is as follows...
Content: Published (Yes)
Content: Type (= Article)